# PHP Mail occasionally sending blank email for variables only

Tags: php, email

I have an online booking form that has been working fine but we have received a couple of booking confirmation emails recently where the static info comes through, but the php variables are not showing in the email. The system is working fine 90% of the time.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
include 'class.phpmailer.php';
$mid = trim(strip_tags($_POST['mid']));
$bintypeconfirm = trim(strip_tags($_POST['bintypeconfirm']));
$bintype = trim(strip_tags($_POST['bintype']));
$amt = trim(strip_tags($_POST['amt']));
$currency = trim(strip_tags($_POST['currency']));
$from = trim(strip_tags($_POST['from']));
$to = trim(strip_tags($_POST['to']));
$pmt_contact_firstname = trim(strip_tags($_POST['pmt_contact_firstname']));
$pmt_contact_surname = trim(strip_tags($_POST['pmt_contact_surname']));
$pmt_contact_phone = trim(strip_tags($_POST['pmt_contact_phone']));
$pmt_sender_email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['pmt_sender_email']));
$regindi_address1 = trim(strip_tags($_POST['regindi_address1']));
$regindi_address2 = trim(strip_tags($_POST['regindi_address2']));
$regindi_sub = trim(strip_tags($_POST['regindi_sub']));
$regindi_state = trim(strip_tags($_POST['regindi_state']));
$regindi_pcode = trim(strip_tags($_POST['regindi_pcode']));
$comments = trim(strip_tags($_POST['comments']));
$agree = trim(strip_tags($_POST['agree']));

$mail = new PHPMailer();       
$body = 'Dear '.$pmt_contact_firstname.', <br><br> We have received your booking and
will be in contact with you as soon as possible to confirm your details.<br>If you have
any further queries you can call us on 1300 826 811.<br>
<table cellpadding="4" width="509">
<tr><th>Skip Bin Details</th></tr>
<tr><td>Bin Size</td><td>'.$bintypeconfirm.'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Bin Type</td><td>'.$bintype.' Waste</td></tr>
<tr><td>Your Price</td><td>$'.$amt.'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Delivery Date</td><td>'.$from.'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Collection Date</td><td>'.$to.'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Additional Comments</td><td>'.$comments.'</td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><th>Customer Details</th></tr>
<tr><td>First Name</td><td>'.$pmt_contact_firstname.'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Last Name</td><td>'.$pmt_contact_surname.'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Phone</td><td>'.$pmt_contact_phone.'</td></tr>
<tr><td>email</td><td>'.$pmt_sender_email.'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Address Line 1</td><td>'.$regindi_address1.'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Address Line 2</td><td>'.$regindi_address2.'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Suburb</td><td>'.$regindi_sub.'</td></tr>
<tr><td>State</td><td>'.$regindi_state.'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Postcode</td><td>'.$regindi_pcode.'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Agree to Ts & Cs</td><td>'.$agree.'</td></tr>
</table>';

$mail->From       = "enquiries@skiptech.com.au";
$mail->FromName   = "Skiptech";

$mail->Subject    = "Your Online Booking Confirmation | Skiptech Skip Bin Hire";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email  
viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAddress($_POST[pmt_sender_email]);
$mail->AddCC('enquiries@skiptech.com.au', 'Skiptech');
if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  header("location:https://www.paymate.com/PayMate/ExpressPayment?mid=xxx
amt_editable=N&currency=AUD&ref=not%20required
pmt_sender_email=".$_POST[pmt_sender_email]."
pmt_contact_firstname=".$_POST[pmt_contact_firstname]."
pmt_contact_surname=".$_POST[pmt_contact_surname]."
pmt_contact_phone=".$_POST[pmt_contact_phone]."&pmt_country=Australia
regindi_state=Queensland&regindi_address1=".$_POST[regindi_address1]."
regindi_address2=".$_POST[regindi_address2]."&regindi_sub=".$_POST[regindi_sub]."
regindi_pcode=".$_POST[regindi_pcode]."&return=http://www.skiptech.com.a
/&amt=".$_POST[amt]);
}
?>
```

Also, here is the form code, this may help further:

```
echo "<form name='form2' id='form2' action='mailsender.php' method='POST'>
        <input type='hidden' name='mid' id='mid' value='skiptech1'>
        <input type='hidden' name='bintypeconfirm' id='bintypeconfirm'  
value='3 Cubic Metre Skip Bin'>
        <input type='hidden' name='amt' id='amt' value=".$a.">
        <input type='hidden' name='bintype' id='bintype' value=".$table.">
        <input type='hidden' name='currency' id='currency' value='AUD'>
        <table class='quote' align='center' width='97%' border='0'>
        <tr><td colspan='2'><h4>Confirm Your Details</h4></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Requested Delivery Date*</td><td><input type='text'
id='from' name='from' /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Requested Collection Date* (max 7 days)</td><td><input
type='text' id='to' name='to' /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>First Name*</td><td><input type='text'
id='pmt_contact_firstname' name='pmt_contact_firstname'
class='validate[required,maxSize[30]]'/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Last Name*</td><td><input type='text'
id='pmt_contact_surname' name='pmt_contact_surname'
class='validate[required,maxSize[30]]'/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Phone/Mobile Number*</td><td><input type='text'
id='pmt_contact_phone' name='pmt_contact_phone' class='validate[required,
maxSize[15]]'/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email*</td><td><input type='text' id='pmt_sender_email'
name='pmt_sender_email' value='' class='validate[required,custom[email,maxSize[50]]'
size='40'/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Delivery Address line 1*</td><td><input type='text'
id='regindi_address1' name='regindi_address1' size='55' class='validate[required,
maxSize[100]]'/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Delivery Address line 2</td><td><input type='text'
id='regindi_address2' name='regindi_address2' size='55'
class='validate[maxSize[100]]'/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Suburb*</td><td><input type='text' id='regindi_sub'
name='regindi_sub' size='40'class='validate[required,maxSize[50]]'/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>State*</td><td><input type='text' id='regindi_state'
value='Queensland' name='regindi_state'
size='40'class='validate[required,maxSize[11]]'/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Postcode*</td><td><input type='text' id='regindi_pcode'
name='regindi_pcode' value=".urldecode($tags)." class='validate[required,maxSize[4]]'/
</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Additional Requirements e.g. where to place bin.</td
<td><textarea id='comments' name='comments' rows='5' cols='45'
class='validate[maxSize[150]]'></textarea></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan='2'><div class='flcheck-wrapper'>Checking this box
indicates that you have read and accepted the Cheap Skip Bin Hire Brisbane Terms &
Conditions for Skip Bin Hire:
        <input type='checkbox' id='agree' name='agree'
class='validate[required]'/></div></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan='2'><div class='pagination'><input type='submit'
id='sender' name='sender' class='quote-button2' value=''/></div></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan='2'></td></tr>
        </table></form>";
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to be enforcing any sort of validation that fields are completed, so perhaps anyone can post the form with blank fields (perhaps by accident) causing you to get an email without fields completed.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain web crawlers which will submit forms on your website. This will cause it to send you an e-mail with nothing entered into the inputs. The solution to prevent this is to add some kind of field validation.

Here is a link on how to do basic Javascript field validation:
http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_form_validation.asp

If you make at least one input require something to be entered then you will stop receiving blank form submittals.

(On a side note, some web crawlers will also fill out and submit your web form with spam. In some cases they will even fill out a CAPTCHA if the distortion settings are low enough.)

Comment: sorry guys there is javascript validation on the fields so it can't be submitted unless all fields are completed. Also, the blank emails are from genuine customers that have made bookings and filled everything out. The form fields are also submitted to the payment system and the payment system is receiving the fields correctly, they just aren't going into the email.

Comment: @glenn Javascript validation is useless if you're being crawled by a bot. It simply won't execute the Javascript, leaving the protection moot. (But if the E-Mails come from legit customers as you say, you'll have to look into why the POST values might be empty. We can't really tell from the code you show.)

Comment: @Pekka웃 I've now added the form code, hopefully this extra info will help?

Comment: Perhaps the customers have JavaScript disabled and hence manage to pass the validation with empty fields? Server side validation would help in that case

Comment: +1 to Pekka's suggestion to add server side validation. It might be that a crawler or user has Javascript disabled. Try something like this:

if($pmt_sender_email == "")
{
//header back to the form
}
else
{
//e-mail the form
}